# How to scroll window to at bottom of page after ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have jQuery ajax code which execute fine on success it give response and I display on page. After displaying response on page I want to window scroll at bottom position.

**My jQuery Code**

```
$("body").scrollTop( $(document).height() - $(window).height() );
```

But it not scroll at bottom of page. How can I achieve? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need jquery for this. The `scrollTo()` method scrolls the document to the specified coordinates.:

```
window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
```